# set the text of an Action Control to a document property

Tags: properties, spotfire

Is there a way to set the text of an Action Control to the value of a document property?

i.e. I have a property FooProp. I want to set the label text of a button to ${FooProp} so that when FooProp gets updated (via script), the button text changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can set the Display Text of a button to a document property.

You could really easily create an HTML button that does similar functionality but could still have a dynamic title. Simply create a button and set the name of the button to a Spotfire Label equal to that Document Property. Then perhaps use a python script or other script to do work e.g. change page, load data, etc. Depends on your use case.

Comment: i gave up on doing this, but eventually got similar functionality with a calculated value (that had a label from the property) that ran a script when clicked